# tikz block diagram widgets for computers, disks, switches, chips, interfaces, etc.

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

is there a widget library for hardware sketches?  I don't mean just block diagrams for circuits (which exists), but for more ordinary diagrams for computer items like speakers, SATA input and output interfaces (which look like SATA ;-) ), computers, motherboards, storage devices (e.g., SSDs), external ports, switches of various kinds, blocks inside blocks (such as inside microcontrollers) and so on?  I want to draw diagrams for novices and drill down ever-deeper.

if not, I better start figuring out how to draw them...an autotracer would be nice.

Comment: I can't see anything at https://www.ctan.org/search/?phrase=tikz at least. You could look at Inkscape for tracing, although `\node {\includegrapics{some-icon-or-whatever}};` is likely easier and faster.

Comment: Google search for images, download the files, (check copyright) and use \includegraphics{filename}.

Comment: A drawn rectangular node will do for most components.  It is relatively easy to create new components using circuitikz.  (See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm)